# how to insert multiple attachments into database in single request from servlet

Tags: hibernate, jsp, servlets

I have inserted a single attachment into database but I am not able to find how to insert multiple files into database.
I have checked lot of websites and somehow implemented how to insert a single attachment into db using servlet and jsp. But I couldn't do this for multiple files. Can anybody help me with how to insert multiple files into database.

Here is the code of inserting single attachment.

```
package com.fileupload.attach;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)
// upload file's size up to 16MB
public class FileUploadDBServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
    // database connection settings
    private String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
    private String dbUser = "root";
    private String dbPass = "password";

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // gets values of text fields
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");

        InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file

        // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
        Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");
        if (filePart != null) {
            // prints out some information for debugging
            System.out.println(filePart.getName());
            System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
            System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

            // obtains input stream of the upload file
            inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
        }

        Connection conn = null; // connection to the database
        String message = null; // message will be sent back to client

        try {
            // connects to the database
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);

            // constructs SQL statement
            String sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (first_name, last_name, photo) values (?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, firstName);
            statement.setString(2, lastName);

            if (inputStream != null) {
                // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
                statement.setBlob(3, inputStream);
            }

            // sends the statement to the database server
            int row = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (row > 0) {
                message = "File uploaded and saved into database";
            }

            String filepath = "D:/Dev/JavaWorkSpaceNew/FileUploadDatabase/WebContent/FromDb.jpg";
            String sql1 = "SELECT photo FROM contacts WHERE first_name=? AND last_name=?";
            PreparedStatement statement1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
            statement1.setString(1, firstName);
            statement1.setString(2, lastName);

            ResultSet result = statement1.executeQuery();
            if (result.next()) {
                Blob blob = result.getBlob("photo");
                InputStream inputStream1 = blob.getBinaryStream();
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filepath);

                int bytesRead = -1;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream1.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                inputStream1.close();
                outputStream.close();
                System.out.println("File saved");

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                // closes the database connection
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // sets the message in request scope
            request.setAttribute("Message", message);

            // forwards to the message page
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Message.jsp").include(
                    request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to get the Multipart request from the form as an array for different files and process each array item as each file and then save it to your database..

Comment: I implemented using servlet and jdbc.Would you mind posting me an example regarding it.Thanks.